# VBA code failure: Application. ScreenUpdating = False not working when calling subs under one button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which requires calling subs under one button. The problem is, Application. ScreenUpdating = False not working when calling subs under one button. Is there a way to solve this? My code is listed below.

```
Sub Button8_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call Copydate
    Call test
    Call CopyStartSMU
    Call CopyEndSMU
    Call UpdateTotalBCM
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have solved this problem by using Application.EnableEvents = False at the beginning of the code and Application.EnableEvents = True at the end of the code.  This is an answer from [Mezhick](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/mezhick/?ws=usercard-mini). Find the comment thread by clicking
[here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c94932a8-9cc4-452e-bbf1-fe550edb2d92/applicationscreenupdating-problems). I hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe some of the subs called from `Button8_Click` contains `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`.

Comment: Add a statement `Debug.Print Application.ScreenUpdating` after every `Call`-statement to check if it is changed back to true.

Comment: Yes, they call for it to be true,  turning them into comments did nothing for the sheet. It is still flickering in and out.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add comment yet. But ScreenUpdating is not working on Office 2013, 2016, 2019 when you open other workbooks due to MDI from 2013 office. I think there is more functions on which screenupdating not working. But you also must check your every function/sub or it's not set to True again.

Comment: I removed Application.ScreenUpdating = True for all the subs, however, it is still flickering.

Comment: Question: are you activating different workbooks?

Comment: @CarolineOlyn Question: are you activating different workbooks?

Comment: Hi, @bankeris . I used the `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top and then set it to `Application.EnableEvents = True` of my code for it to work. Excuse me for the late reply.

Comment: @CarolineOlyn you forgot to answer: does your code activating/opening other worbooks, worksheets?

Comment: yes, it does. But, the above code helped the code stop flickering.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that Application.ScreenUpdating applies to the active workbook. `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` immediately after opening or activating another workbook in the VBA code, prevents the screen from flickering while working on that other workbook.